# get average length of words using python reduce

Tags: python

I am attempting to get the average length of words in a file using reduce, but I am getting the following error "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()" which i find baffling because the file is filled with words and I am simply getting the length of each

```
def averageWord():
    myWords =  open('myfile.txt', 'r').read().split(' ')
    avg = (reduce(lambda x,y: len(x) + len(y) ,myWords)) / len(myWords)
    print avg
```

Comment: Use `sum()` with a generator expression not `reduce`. With `reduce` it will be unnecessarily complicated: `reduce(lambda x, y: x + len(y), myWords, 0)`.

Comment: why does only the second argument have a call to len and why is there a 0 as the last parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function will work upon two elements of the list at a time and then work with the returned value along with the next element. So the `reduce` function is used in a wrong way. Quoting from the docs

> Apply function of two arguments **cumulatively** to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value. For example, `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calculates `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`.

(emphasis mine)

Using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) along with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) is a better way ([as mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414131/get-average-length-of-words-using-python-reduce#comment47000855_29414131))

That is

```
avg = sum(map(len,myWords)) /len(myWords)
```

This would give you the average as expected

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes surely. But the OP had used it wrongly here! :) Just like you had mentioned above, it is a quite complicated procedure! I just tried to explain to the OP about that!